# Deploying Delphi custom component to Android and IOS

Tags: delphi, deployment, mobile-application, delphi-xe4, delphi-xe5

I have created a mobile application for android and ios with Delphi XE5. I needed a custom component, so I created a package and I wrote my component. I wrote a windows application for testing my custom compnent and every thing is OK so far. I add an instance of my component on the Firemonkey mobile form in design time and it shows it correctly. But when I try to run app on IOS Simulator or Android emulator it crashes, I think the problem is caused by not deploying my package along with my app, but I don't know how should I include this package in my mobile app deployment. Any idea?

P.S I know how to deploy database files to Android and IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run time packages are not supported under iOS. Just statically link your component to your application.

Comment: Hi Farncois, thanks for response, would you tell me how should I statically link component to application? (Any article, sample, blog ?) Do I need to do something special(I don't load the package dynamically, I just create a package and install it and use its component on the mobile application form )?

Comment: In the project option, don't select "use runtime packages" and make the source code of your package available to your application (dcu is good also).